# How to delete Text in C?

Tags: c, justify

Here is basically the problem. I am given a huge file. A text, that has a lot of blank spaces. I must write a program that removes the blank spaces, creates lines of exactly 80 characters long without splitting any word, and it will align the text to left and right simultaneously (justify text); The text is justified by placing additional spaces between words so that the line will end with a word and start with word, being exactly 80 chars long.

Yes this is a homework, but I am allowed to get any kind of online help. My code this far is able to do everything but align the text (justify):

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "catalin.h"

int main()
{
   char text[145000], blank[1450000],c;
   FILE *input, *output;
   int n,f=80,i=0,j,l;
   input = fopen("asimov.in", "r");
   while ((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF){
      if (c=='\n') c=' ';
      text[i]=c; 
      i++;
   }
   fclose(input);
   blankremove(text,blank);
   wrap(blank,f);
   l=lenght(blank);
   output = fopen("out.out", "w");
   fprintf(output,blank);
}

int blankremove(char text[], char blank[])
{
   int c = 0, d = 0;
   while (text[c] != '\0') {
      if (text[c] == ' ') {
         int temp = c + 1;
         if (text[temp] != '\0') {
            while (text[temp] == ' ' && text[temp] != '\0') {
               if (text[temp] == ' ') {
                  c++;
               }
               temp++;
            }
         }
      }
      blank[d] = text[c];
      c++;
      d++;
   }
   blank[d] = '\0';
}

void wrap(char s[], const int wrapline)
{
    int i, k, wraploc, lastwrap;

    lastwrap = 0;
    wraploc = 0; //catalin

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i, ++wraploc) {
        if (wraploc >= wrapline) {
            for (k = i; k > 0; --k) {
                // posibil are overflow
                if (k - lastwrap <= wrapline && s[k] == ' ') {
                    s[k] = '\n';
                    lastwrap = k+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            wraploc = i-lastwrap;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < wrapline; ++i) printf(" ");
    printf("|\n");
}
```

All I need is some help on creating a function that justifies the text. "justified—text is aligned along the left margin, and letter- and word-spacing is adjusted so that the text falls flush with both margins, also known as fully justified or full justification;" The spaces created when doing justification should be placed uniformly. No libraries should be used other than the default.

Comment: Hasn't that been asked earlier today?

Comment: @Jabberwocky yes but since I am a newbie on this website, I didn't give a good explanation and the code I gave was bad. Therefore I deleted that post and posted this one.

Comment: A couple of (possibly) unrelated notes: Please try to use descriptive variable names. Use comments to describe what's happening. Declare functions before calling them. The [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an `int` (which is important for that `EOF` comparison). Do error checking (what happens if `fopen` fails for example?). Don't put large arrays as local variables. You never zero-terminate the arrays. You don't check for bounds of the arrays.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sure, but the code works in 100% of the cases, althought I agree on better describing the code and not creating that large arrays. The thing is, I am given a file of max 1.44mb, that's why I decided to allocate enough size to the array so that it wont overflow.

Comment: Trust me, it doesn't work. If you don't explicitly zero-terminate `text` then you will go into the uninitialized parts of that array (where the values are *indeterminate* and could seem random), and possibly out of bounds of it as well. That's [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). I'd say you're *unlucky* that it seems to work for you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how to do it? How to zero terminate?

Comment: You do it in the `blankremove` function, so you clearly know how to terminate a string properly

Comment: @ChrisTurner, I am just learning into another language and I may not know the English equivalent

Comment: `blank[d] = '\0';` is you NUL terminating the string

Comment: @ChrisTurner thanks for the help, but got any suggestions, maybe some sample code for the problem I cant solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  thanks for the help, but got any suggestions, maybe some sample code for the problem I cant solve?

Comment: Not sure why it's difficult to apply what you've done to the `text` string - it's just `text[i]='\0';`

Comment: @ChrisTurner I mean, text justifying

Comment: Your program will fail miserably if the `asimov.in` does niot exist.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I stated that this is a homework, and this is the name of the file that the professor will give us to test the application. Everything works perfectly this far with the exception of the justifying text part. In Asimov.in any text can be used. Any Wikipedia article, book, and so on is good enough.

Comment: You don't check if the file exists could be opened correctly. If the file could not be opened for example because it doesn't exist (yes files frequently don't exist), `fopen` returns `NULL` and guess what happens then.

Comment: One issue to fix: After `while ((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF){`, add `text[i]='\0';`  Else `text` is not a _string_.

Comment: What is code `while (text[temp] == ' ' && text[temp] != '\0') {` trying to test?  If `text[temp] == ' '` is true, then of course `text[temp] != '\0'` is also true.

Comment: Post some sample input used, your actual output seen and expected output.  This will add clarity to the question.

Comment: @user3121023 of course i can. At this point i am even ready to offer a bounty for solving this problem. not much, about 5-10$, because this is an easy to resolve problem.

Comment: @user3121023 no libraries other than default. I created functions for the first 3, if it will help you resolve my problem. https://pastebin.com/AAQdvwt7

Comment: @user3121023 are you up for the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fscanf` will read words and exclude whitespace.
Then add words while the length of the line is less than 80.
Add extra spaces to right justify the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int len ( char *str);
char *cat ( char *to, char *from);
char *cpy ( char *to, char *from);
char *lastchr ( char *str, int ch);
char *justify ( char *str, int wordcount, int width);

int main( void) {
    char word[100] = "";
    char line[100] = "";
    char filenamein[] = "asimov.in";
    char filenameout[] = "out.out";
    int length = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int pending = 0;
    FILE *pfin = NULL;
    FILE *pfout = NULL;
    if ( NULL == ( pfin = fopen ( filenamein, "r"))) {
        perror ( filenamein);
        return 0;
    }
    if ( NULL == ( pfout = fopen ( filenameout, "w"))) {
        fclose ( pfin);
        perror ( filenameout);
        return 0;
    }

    while ( 1 == fscanf ( pfin, "%99s", word)) {//read a word from file. will exclude whitespace
        length = len ( word);
        if ( 80 > len ( line) + length) {//add to line if it will fit
            cat ( line, word);
            cat ( line, " ");
            wordcount++;//needed in case more than one extra space per word
            pending = 1;
        }
        else {//adding last word would be more than 80
            justify ( line, wordcount, 80);

            fprintf ( pfout, "%s\n", line);

            cpy ( line, word);//copy pending word to line
            cat ( line, " ");//add a space
            wordcount = 1;//reset wordcount
            pending = 0;
        }
    }
    if ( pending) {
        justify ( line, wordcount, 80);
        fprintf ( pfout, "%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose ( pfin);
    fclose ( pfout);

    return 0;
}

int len ( char *str) {
    int length = 0;

    while ( *str) {//not at terminating zero
        length++;
        str++;
    }
    return length;
}

char *cat ( char *to, char *from) {
    char *start = to;
    while ( *to) {//not at terminating zero
        to++;
    }
    while ( *from) {
        *to = *from;//assign from to to
        to++;
        from++;
    }
    *to = 0;//terminate
    return start;
}

char *cpy ( char *to, char *from) {
    *to = 0;//set first character of to as terminating zero
    cat ( to, from);
    return to;
}

char *lastchr ( char *str, int ch) {
    char *found = NULL;
    while ( *str) {//not at terminating zero
        if ( ch == *str) {
            found = str;//set pointer
        }
        str++;//keep searching
    }
    return found;//return NULL or last found match
}

char *justify ( char *str, int wordcount, int width) {
    int length = 0;
    int addspaces = 0;
    int extraspace = 0;

    char *space = lastchr ( str, ' ');//find the last space
    *space = 0;//set it to terminate the line
    space--;//deduct one
    length = len ( str);
    addspaces = width - length;//difference is number of spaces needed
    extraspace = addspaces / wordcount;//may need more than one extra space
    char *end = space + addspaces;
    while ( addspaces) {
        *end = *space;//shift characters toward end
        if ( ' ' == *space) {//found a space
            for ( int each = 0; each <= extraspace; ++each) {//will add at least one space
                end--;
                *end = ' ';
                addspaces--;
                if ( ! addspaces) {
                    break;//do not need to add more spaces
                }
            }
        }
        end--;
        space--;
        if ( space <= str) {//reached the start of the line
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH 80
#define SIZE ( WIDTH + 20)

int len ( char *str);
char *cat ( char *to, char *from);
char *cpy ( char *to, char *from);
char *lastchr ( char *str, int ch);
char *justify ( char *str, int wordcount, int width);
int scanword ( FILE *pfread, int size, char *word);

int main( void) {
    char word[SIZE] = "";
    char line[SIZE] = "";
    char filenamein[] = "asimov.in";
    char filenameout[] = "out.out";
    int length = 0;
    int wordcount = 0;
    int pending = 0;
    //int paragraph = 1;
    FILE *pfin = NULL;
    FILE *pfout = NULL;
    if ( NULL == ( pfin = fopen ( filenamein, "r"))) {
        perror ( filenamein);
        return 0;
    }
    if ( NULL == ( pfout = fopen ( filenameout, "w"))) {
        fclose ( pfin);
        perror ( filenameout);
        return 0;
    }

    while ( 1 == scanword ( pfin, WIDTH, word)) {//read a word from file
        length = len ( word);
        if ( '\n' != word[0] && WIDTH > len ( line) + length) {//add to line if it will fit
            if ( 0 != word[0]) {
                cat ( line, word);
                cat ( line, " ");
                wordcount++;//needed in case more than one extra space per word
                pending = 1;//a line is pending
            }
        }
        else {//paragraph or adding last word would be more than 80
            if ( len ( line)) {//line has content
                justify ( line, wordcount, WIDTH);

                fprintf ( pfout, "%s\n", line);
                //paragraph = 1;//could have a blank line
            }
            if ( /*paragraph &&*/ '\n' == word[0]) {
                fprintf ( pfout, "\n");//print a blank line for paragraph
                //paragraph = 0;//only allow one blank line
            }

            line[0] = 0;
            wordcount = 0;//reset wordcount
            if ( 0 != word[0] && '\n' != word[0]) {//word is not empty and is not newline
                cpy ( line, word);//copy pending word to line
                cat ( line, " ");//add a space
                wordcount = 1;//reset wordcount
            }
            pending = 0;//nothing pending
        }
    }
    if ( pending) {//print pending line
        if ( len ( line)) {//line has content
            justify ( line, wordcount, WIDTH);
            fprintf ( pfout, "%s\n", line);
        }
    }

    fclose ( pfin);
    fclose ( pfout);

    return 0;
}

int scanword ( FILE *pfread, int size, char *word) {
    static int nl = 0;//static to retain value between function calls
    int ch = 0;
    int max = size - 1;//max characters that can fit in word and leave one to terminate

    *word = 0;//first character. zero terminate. empty line
    while ( max && ( ch = fgetc ( pfread))) {//read a character until max is zero
        if ( EOF == ch) {//end of file
            if ( max == size - 1) {
                return 0;//no other characters read
            }
            return 1;//process the other characters that were read
        }
        if ( '\n' == ch) {//read a newline
            if ( '\n' == nl) {//consecutive newlines
                *word = nl;
                word++;
                *word = 0;
                //nl = 0;//reset since just had two consceutive newlines
                return 1;
            }
            nl = ch;//set for first single newline
            return 1;
        }
        nl = 0;//reset to zero as prior character was not newline
        if ( ' ' == ch || '\t' == ch) {//read space or tab
            if ( max == size - 1) {//no characters in word so far
                continue;//consume leading space and tab
            }
            return 1;//process the word read
        }
        *word = ch;//assign character to word
        word++;//increment pointer to next character
        *word = 0;//zero terminate
        max--;//deduct. one less charater can be read into word
    }
    return 0;
}

int len ( char *str) {
    int length = 0;

    while ( *str) {//character pointed to is not terminating zero
        length++;
        str++;//increment pointer to point to next character
    }
    return length;
}

char *cat ( char *to, char *from) {
    char *iterate = to;
    while ( *iterate) {//character pointed to is not terminating zero
        iterate++;//increment pointer to point to next character
    }
    while ( *from) {//character pointed to is not terminating zero
        *iterate = *from;//assign from to iterate
        iterate++;//increment pointer to point to next character
        from++;
    }
    *iterate = 0;//terminate
    return to;
}

char *cpy ( char *to, char *from) {
    *to = 0;//set first character of to as terminating zero
    cat ( to, from);
    return to;
}

char *lastchr ( char *str, int ch) {
    char *found = NULL;
    while ( *str) {//character pointed to is not terminating zero
        if ( ch == *str) {//character pointed to matches ch
            found = str;//assign pointer str to found
        }
        str++;//increment pointer to point to next character. keep searching
    }
    return found;//return NULL or pointer to last found match
}

char *justify ( char *str, int wordcount, int width) {
    int length = 0;
    int addspaces = 0;
    int extraspace = 0;

    char *space = lastchr ( str, ' ');//find the last space
    *space = 0;//set it to terminate the line
    space--;//deduct one
    length = len ( str);
    addspaces = width - length;//difference is number of spaces needed
    extraspace = addspaces;//may need more than one extra space
    if ( wordcount > 2) {
        extraspace = addspaces / ( wordcount - 1);//may need more than one extra space
    }
    char *end = space + addspaces;//set pointer end to point beyond wheree space points

    while ( addspaces) {//stop when addspaces is zero
        *end = *space;//assign character pointed to by space to the location pointed to by end
        if ( ' ' == *space) {//found a space
            for ( int each = 0; each <= extraspace; ++each) {//will add at least one space
                end--;
                *end = ' ';
                addspaces--;
                if ( ! addspaces) {
                    break;//do not need to add more spaces
                }
            }
        }
        end--;
        space--;
        if ( space <= str) {//reached the start of the line
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: it works great, it has only one problem. here is an example: https://pastebin.com/H423MfgU , when the program runs, some words at the end are missing. Any solutions? and please add a bit more comments on how this works. thanks for the huge help by the way. I was not kidding about the bounty...

Comment: i started learning pointers not long ago. Can you explain a bit more: Things like this require a bit more explanation. 
while ( *str) {//not at terminating zero
        if ( ch == *str) {
            found = str;//set pointer

thanks a lot btw, please provide a paypal address, if you got any...

Comment: what does the cat and cpy function do?

Comment: can you please edit the program so that if 2  new lines are present, it will create a paragraph

Comment: i summon you again my savior

Comment: I can easily use fgetc in a while loop for !=EOF , but this will mean that most of the code need to be tweaked. I basically need if there is an empty line, and the next line has characters, then the empty line must be saved into the output. Basically, the code should keep the empty lines, but it seems I don't have enough knowledge yet for that.

Comment: I used such a code before, but I cant find how to put it in your code. My code looks smth like this:
while ((c=fgetc(input))!=EOF){
   text[i]=c; i++;}

where c is a char type.

Comment: so I basically create a function :
int scanword ( FILE *pfread, int size, char *word);
{
    int c;
    while ( c = fgetc ( pfread)!=EOF){}
    return 0;
}

and replace fscanf with this function?

Comment: I have written:
int scanword ( FILE *pfread, int size, char *word);
{
    int i;
    char c;
    while ((c=fgetc(pfread))!=EOF){
   word[i]=c; i++;}
}

but I cant fit the int size in the function, nor it works

Comment: the program now goes into infinite loop, and I think size is still no used properly.
https://pastebin.com/4kxQc81f

Comment: I would understand more if I were to see a working code, I know I demand much from you, since you helped me a lot , but that's the way I learn. I basically learnt pointers based on your code.

Comment: basically could you please edit your program, if got the time of course. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the many bugs in your existing code, you need to think about what you're trying to achieve.

Think about a more simple example to start with. Say your source text is "Hello world" and you're justifying it to a width of 15. "Hello world" is 11 characters long, which is 4 less than we need. There is 1 space in the string, so you know you need to make that space become 5 spaces so that it becomes "Hello     world".

Next example: "I like bees!" - that is 12 characters, but it has 2 spaces and you need an extra 3 spaces in there. One of those spaces has to become 2 spaces and the other 3 spaces to fill out the 15 characters.

So your code needs to firstly, count how many spaces are in the line you're currently working with. You can do that whilst you're working out where to wrap the line and also if you track where the last space is, you don't then need to back track to find it again.

Secondly, know how many extra characters it needs to pad it out by.

And finally find the spaces within the line and add extra spaces evenly amongst them. You'd be better off working with a new string at this point because whilst it's possible to insert spaces into `s`, it's complicated and more likely to introduce more bugs.

Comment: well, I already have some concepts that work in theory, but I cant apply them using code because they involve too many operations.

Comment: i would appreciate if you could give me a code sample for that, since I am still a beginner,  this is what my program outputs now : https://pastebin.com/nwfv7BkB

this is the initial input : https://pastebin.com/sttCRf5y

Comment: which part? you've already written code that does all 3 parts. Like the 3rd part is exactly the same as what you're doing in `blankremove`, except you're potentially adding extra spaces when you encounter a space